# Loop through array parameter WITHOUT foreach

Tags: postgresql, foreach, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnMyFunction(recipients recipient[]) ...

    FOREACH v_recipient IN ARRAY recipients
       LOOP
          v_total := v_total + v_recipient.amount;
          INSERT INTO tmp_recipients(id, amount)
          VALUES(v_recipient.id, v_recipient.amount::numeric(10,2));
    END LOOP;

...
```

This works great in dev environment, but just found out the release environment is 8.4 which doesn't appear to support the FOREACH construct.  I was hoping someone might shed some light on an alternative implementation for loop though the array parameter set and using values from array in a similar fashion to avoid a complete refactor.

The error message I am receiving is:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "FOREACH" SQL state: 42601 Context: SQL
>   statement in PL/PgSQL function "fnMyFunction" near line ##

The db environment is on a shared host so I have no options for platform upgrade.
I tagged postgres 9.1 and 8.4 because the function works properly in 9.x but fails on 8.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html); I think it was in 8.4. Untested but I think is right:

```
FOR v_recipient IN SELECT vr FROM unnest(recipients) x(vr)
LOOP
....
END LOOP;
```

If you can't do that you'll have to loop over `array_length` using indexing into the array.

Comment: So it looks like this works, unfortunately I'm not finding a clear explanation of unnest.  The issue now is I seem to be getting the first item in the v_recipient element but not the 2nd.  The recipient element is based on a two fields id and amount i'm assuming the structure would look something like: {{1,1.00},{2,1.00}}

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it, you execute one `INSERT` at a time. With relational databases, set-based operations are regularly *much* faster than iterating through records one at a time.

This should be simpler, faster and work with PostgreSQL 8.4 or later:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_recipients(id, amount)
SELECT (r.col).*
FROM   (SELECT unnest(recipients) AS col) r
```

This assumes that the composite base type of the array consists of `(id, amount)` - in that order - and the type of `amount` can be coerced to `numeric(10,2)`. Else, or just to be sure, be more explicit:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_recipients(id, amount)
SELECT (r.col).id, (r.col).amount::numeric(10,2)
FROM   (SELECT unnest(recipients) AS col) r
```

The parentheses around `(r.col)` are not optional. They are required to disambiguate the syntax for the composite type.